# Insert to database with field name TA/TJ with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Recently I've been assigned to a project where we have to migrate an old VB3 process to C#, this process takes data from an Access 97 file and Insert it into SQL Server, the problem is that some 'genius' call a field "Ta/Tj" and the '/' is breaking our code, we tried different ways but fail. We can't change the field name right now because we don't know exactly how many programs use that table.

Here is my code

```
    OleDbConnection connectionEpsOle = new OleDbConnection();
        SqlConnection connectionEpsSql = (SqlConnection)GetConexion.GetConnectionIus();
        DbDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        long nIus;
        long nIdGenealogia;
        string sRubroStr;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataRow dr;

        string sqlCadena = "SELECT * FROM Tesis WHERE ius =0";

        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCadena, connectionEpsSql);

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Tesis");

        sRubroStr = tesisDto.RUBRO;
        sRubroStr = MiscFunct.QuitaCarCad(sRubroStr);
        sRubroStr = MiscFunct.ConvMay(sRubroStr);
        sRubroStr = MiscFunct.QuitaDblEspacio(sRubroStr);
        sRubroStr = sRubroStr.Trim();

        if (sRubroStr.Length > 250)
        {
            sRubroStr = sRubroStr.Substring(0, 250);
        }

        dr = dataSet.Tables["Tesis"].NewRow();

        dr["IUS"] = tesisDto.IUS;
        dr["Parte"] = 200;
        dr["Consec"] = 0;
        dr["Rubro"] = tesisDto.RUBRO;
        dr["Texto"] = tesisDto.TEXTO;
        dr["Prec"] = tesisDto.PRECEDENTES;
        dr["Epoca"] = tesisDto.Epoca;
        dr["Sala"] = tesisDto.Sala;
        dr["Fuente"] = tesisDto.Fuente;
        dr["Volumen"] = tesisDto.Volumen;
        dr["Tesis"] = tesisDto.Tesis;
        dr["Pagina"] = tesisDto.Pagina;
        dr["TA/TJ"] = tesisDto.TATJ;
        dr["Materia1"] = tesisDto.Materia1;
        dr["Materia2"] = tesisDto.Materia2;
        dr["Materia3"] = tesisDto.Materia3;
        dr["IdGenealogia"] = tesisDto.idGenealogia;
        dr["ConsecIndx"] = 0;
        dr["IdTCC"] = 0;
        dr["InfAnexos"] = 0; 
        dr["LocAbr"] = " ";
        dr["NumLetra"] = 0;
        dr["ConsecLetra"] = 0;
        dr["Instancia"] = 0;
        dr["ConsecInst"] = 0;
        dr["LocExp"] = " ";
        dr["RIndx"] = "RRR";
        dr["TIndx"] = "TTT";
        dr["PIndx"] = "PPP";
        dr["LIndx"] = "LLL";
        dr["Certificada"] = 0;
        dr["IdSubVolumen"] = 0;

        dataSet.Tables["Tesis"].Rows.Add(dr);

        //dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = connectionEpsSQL.CreateCommand();
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand = connectionEpsSql.CreateCommand();
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tesis(IUS,Parte,Consec,Rubro,Texto,Prec," +
                                                "Epoca,Sala,Fuente,Volumen,Tesis,Pagina,[TA/TJ],Materia1,Materia2,Materia3," +
                                                "IdGenealogia,ConsecIndx,IdTCC,InfAnexos,LocAbr,NumLetra,ConsecLetra,Instancia," +
                                                "ConsecInst,LocExp,RIndx,TIndx,PIndx,LIndx,Certificada,IdSubVolumen)" +
                                                " VALUES(@IUS,@Parte,@Consec,@Rubro,@Texto,@Prec," +
                                                "@Epoca,@Sala,@Fuente,@Volumen,@Tesis,@Pagina,@[TA/TJ],@Materia1,@Materia2,@Materia3," +
                                                "@IdGenealogia,@ConsecIndx,@IdTCC,@InfAnexos,@LocAbr,@NumLetra,@ConsecLetra," +
                                                "@Instancia,@                                                ConsecInst,@LocExp,@RIndx,@TIndx,@PIndx," +
                                                "@LIndx,@Certificada,@IdSubVolumen)";

        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IUS", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "IUS");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parte", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Parte");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Consec", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Consec");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Rubro", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "Rubro");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Texto", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "Texto");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Prec", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "Prec");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Epoca", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Epoca");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Sala", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Sala");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Fuente", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Fuente");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Volumen", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Volumen");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tesis", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, "Tesis");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Pagina", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, "Pagina");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[TA/TJ]", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "TA/TJ");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Materia1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Materia1");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Materia2", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Materia2");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Materia3", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Materia3");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdGenealogia", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "IdGenealogia");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConsecIndx", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ConsecIndx");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@idTCC", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 0, "idTCC");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@InfAnexos", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 0, "InfAnexos");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocAbr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, "LocAbr");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@NumLetra", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 0, "NumLetra");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConsecLetra", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ConsecLetra");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Instancia", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 0, "Instancia");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConsecInst", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ConsecInst");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocExp", SqlDbType.NText, 0, "LocExp");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@RIndx", SqlDbType.NText, 0, "RIndx");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TIndx", SqlDbType.NText, 0, "TIndx");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@PIndx", SqlDbType.NText, 0, "PIndx");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LIndx", SqlDbType.NText, 0, "LIndx");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Certificada", SqlDbType.TinyInt, 0, "Certificada");
        ((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSubVolumen", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSubVolumen");


        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "Tesis");

        dataSet.Dispose();
        dataAdapter.Dispose();
        connectionEpsOle.Close();
```

The `Ta/Tj` column holds `tinyint` values

Here is the SqlException message

> *Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'int'. Must declare the variable '@'.*

Comment: Why does your parameter need to have the `/`?... just remove it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff the parameter  have the / because for some reason i thought that it has to be named as the field in the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the columns and variables in their unfortunate state. Just change the parameter name you are passing to something OLE compatible:

In VALUES list: use `@TA_TJ` instead of `@[TA/TJ]`

In list of params change to:

```
((SqlDataAdapter)dataAdapter).InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TA_TJ", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "TA/TJ");
```